# I wanna know this font name

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts, typography

[image]
Hello there, This Design seems great to me ... especially font. So I wanna know this font name .. thank u

Answer (score 2):

Probably [Orator](https://www.fontspring.com/fonts/adobe/orator-std).

Found with Font Squirrel Matcherator.

[image]